# Odd number of double characters in a line (GREP)

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

I need to write a regular expression in Unix using **grep**, which finds lines where the double characters appear an odd number of times.

For example:

```
unix AA unixAA unix helpme AA //**true**, because 'AA' occurs 3 times

??red blue pink yellow red pink //**true**, because '??' occurs once

unixA unixAA unix unixAA  unix    //**false**, because 'AA' occurs 2 times

??red blue?? pink?? yellow??  //**false**, because '??' occurs 4 times
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: What if there is `AAA`? Does that count as 1, or 2, or none?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. But I think it counts as none. What if there was  `AAAA`? In this task I need to find double characters, not triple, quadruple etc.

Comment: the last line contains `ll` in `yellow` odd number of times. It also "deverse" to be `true`

Comment: It wasn't on purpose. I missed that one :)

Comment: the 2nd line has 2 doubled characters `??` and `ll` - even number

Comment: `??' occurs once and `ll` occurs once. So I think this line is correct for two reasons.

Comment: I would solve this with Python in a more clear and straight-forward way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty complicated regex problem. You will need gnu grep to be able to use 
lookaheads to solve this complex regex:

```
^(?:(?!(.)\1).)*((.)\3)((?:(?:(?!\2).)*\2){2})*(?:(?!\2).)*$
```

Using in `grep`:

```
grep -P '^(?:(?!(.)\1).)*((.)\3)((?:(?:(?!\2).)*\2){2})*(?:(?!\2).)*$' file

unix AA unixAA unix helpme AA
??red blue pink yellow red pink
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UObrNW/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
^                         # Start
(?:(?!(.)\1).)*           # Match 0+ characters that don't repeat at start
((.)\3)                   # Match 2 repeats of same character and capture in group #2
((?:(?:(?!\2).)*\2){2})*  # match 0+ occurrence of some text followed by group #2 
(?:(?!\2).)*              # match anything in the end that doesn't have group #2
$                         # End
```

Comment: Proof-positive that, at some point, you should code up a simple parser rather than produce unreadable regex mishmash :-)

Comment: Agreed. If I have to solve this problem I will think 3 times before using regex. I just posted this because question was about `regex` and `grep`.

Comment: That's the first time in 4 years on StackOverflow that I have wanted to both up-vote and down-vote the same answer :-) Up for the ability to write it, down for its illegibility!

Comment: Yes, but I just wonder if a line :
`AAAA AA` 
should be correct. In this task it is not specified.
Anyway, I think this solution is an answer to my problem.

Comment: Well `AAAA AA` has 3 pairs of `AA` so it should match.

Comment: One more question: how can this regex work with only grep? Without -P?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer that `-P (PCRE)` will be required because we are using lookaheads here. Without `-P` option, `grep` doesn't support lookahead expressions.

Comment: So there isn't any solution just in grep?  I am asking because in this task I was asked to save the solution in a file and then run the program with : `grep -f file data`

Comment: If `-P` is removed then it won't be possible in a single `grep` command.